# Subtract 6 Hours From timestamp Using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code to display a date and time from the database.  How would I modify it to subtract 6 hours from the timestamp.

```
date('m-d g:Ga', strtotime($row['time_stamp']))
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

UNIX time stamps are seconds since the Epoch. Simply subtract the number of seconds in six hours:

```
date('m-d g:Ga', strtotime($row['time_stamp'])-21600)
```

You could alternatively use `strtotime` again:

```
date('m-d g:Ga', strtotime('-6 hours', strtotime($row['time_stamp'])))
```

Comment: This worked for subtracting the time.  However, without adding the -21600 onto it, it echos out as 3:03am.  When I add the -21600 onto it it then echos out as 9:21pm.  How am I losing time there?

Comment: 21600s = 6 hours so you must not be operating on the same timestamp both times.

Answer (score 4):

Since it's in MySQL, you can have MySQL do the calculation for you:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('...', DATE_SUB(time_stamp, INTERVAL 6 HOUR)) ...
```

This would save you the overhead of MySQL having to conver its internal representation into a full string, and the overhead of PHP's strtotime() parseing that string just to turn it back into yet another string. While strtotime is magical sometimes, it's definitely not efficient.

Answer (score 0):

$vindate=date('H:i:s', strtotime($row['ms_attend_time'])+19800);
         echo $vindate;